# fix Google Table header in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-visualization

I am using `google visualization table` to create a `html table`. And I fixed the top part of html, using the `stuckpart` div, so that no matter how I scroll across the page, the button is always fixed. Now I also want the table `header` to be fixed just under the `button`. My layout is like this:

```
<div class="stuckpart">
        <button type="button">this button is fixeddddddd</button>
</div>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

I got something working like this: http://jsfiddle.net/RjHMH/95/

As you can see, the table header is not fixed. From the `Firefox`, I can see that the table's header class is `google-visualization-table-tr-head`. Is there anyway I can fix this header and just scroll through the table body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/RjHMH/119/

I changed some of the strange positions and added a height to the actual table and set that table body to scroll.

```
.stuckpart{
position:fixed;
z-index: 100; /*So easy, if you don't know z-index that mean you sucks*/
}

#table_div{
position:relative;
overflow-y:auto; 
padding-top: 40px;
height:400px;
}
tbody{
overflow-y:scroll;
}
```